# How do I get rid of single quotes from a dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, code-behind

I've got the following code that fills a dataset used to populate nodes in a treeview:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ACCT_GRP], [ACCT_GRP_PK] FROM [ACCT_GRP_LIST] " + 
    "ORDER BY [ACCT_GRP] ASC", con4);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    DataSet PrSet = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(PrSet, "ACCT_GRP");   
    TreeViewAccts.Nodes.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow dr in PrSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        TreeNode tnParent = new TreeNode();
        tnParent.Text = dr["ACCT_GRP"].ToString();
        tnParent.Value = dr["ACCT_GRP_PK"].ToString();
        tnParent.PopulateOnDemand = true;
        tnParent.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;
        TreeViewAccts.Nodes.Add(tnParent);
        FillTree_Child(tnParent, tnParent.Text.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ae)
{
    Response.Write(ae.Message);
    //ErrorLogging.WriteToEventLog(ae);
}
```

Of course, what's happening is that if one of my ACCT_GRP names has an apostrophe in it (i.e. "John's Bakery"), it throws an error.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  I think I need a `Replace` command, but I have no idea of the proper syntax for it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: have you done a google search on how to use the `string.Replace` method ..you would want to use it at the end or your dr for example 
`tnParent.Text = dr["ACCT_GRP"].ToString().Replace("'"; "''")`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tnParent.Text = dr["ACCT_GRP"].ToString().Replace("'"; "''");
```

Comment: @JohnnyBones, there are a lot of cool things you can do with `string.Replace` and you can also have multiple string.Replace calls inline as well

Comment: This worked, except I had to change the semicolon inside the Replace brackets to a comma.  Thanks!

Comment: sounds Good @JohnnyBones

Answer (score 1):

So if you take the string can you do a replace like so.

```
string parent = tnParent.Replace("'","''");
```

Then place parent string in?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace using tsql too:

`SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT REPLACE([ACCT_GRP], '''', '') as ACCT_GRP, [ACCT_GRP_PK] FROM [ACCT_GRP_LIST] " + 
    "ORDER BY [ACCT_GRP] ASC", con4);`